# Difference between a magnitude, and a euclidean norm?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I don't quite understand if there is an explicit difference between the magnitude of a vector vs. the euclidean norm of a vector? Are they both the same thing mathematically speaking, but have different physical interpretations? Thank you.

Comment: Good question. It seems (to me) they are the same thing, just different names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe are the same thing, just different names.